# List permissions for Sharepoint Groups

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a list in Sharepoint online. The users have a hierarchy that goes like this. Department Owner Group is the owner of this group. I have three other groups - Team 1, Team 2 and Team 3. Each of the Teams have Users in it. All the Teams have "Contribute" permissions.For example, Team 1 has User 1 and User 2.
Now, a User 1 from Team 1 inputs an "Item" into the list. I don't want any of the members from Team 2 and Team 3 view that "Item". To do that, I set Item Level permissions as "Read Items that were created by the User" and "Create items and edit items that were created by the user". This ensures that users from Team 2 and Team 3 Groups have no visibility of that "Item".
However, I want User 2 from Team 1 to view and edit items that belong to Team 1. How do I do this?

Explained above in the previous section

Comment: You need to post what language you're doing it in and your attempted code.

Comment: This is a setting in Sharepoint Online. So, there is no language associated with it. Same goes to attempted code.

Comment: Then why did you post this in a venue for software development and programming?  This is not your personal technical support forum.

Comment: I have tagged the question with this. I thought 
 is the correct place. Based on your comments, I think I have to look at the right category to post it. Being my first time here, will figure out the correct place to post it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint-online

Comment: You can post this question in Stack Exchange here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ which is dedicated to SharePoint administration.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, you cannot do it using SharePoint out of the box "Advanced settings > Item level permissions".

You will have to break permissions inheritance at individual item level and grant the permissions to your "team" groups.

If you are storing the team name or some related information against each list item to identify item belongs to each team, you can manage permissions using the Power automate flow or you will have to manually manage the permissions.

Follow below steps for automating permissions management:

1. Create a SharePoint group for each team (if not created already).
2. Create a power automate flow which will run on item creation or update (as per your requirements).
3. Break permissions inheritance on newly created item using power automate flow.
4. Grant permissions to respective SharePoint group based on selection of "Team".
5. For safer side grant full control permissions to site admin as well on each list item.

Follow below article for breaking and granting permissions: [Power Automate - Break Inheritance And Set List Item-Level Permissions In SharePoint Online](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/power-automate-break-inheritance-and-set-list-item-level-permissions-in-sharep/)

**Related read**:

1. [View/edit rows in SharePoint List that only relevant to the specific team](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/304080/view-edit-rows-in-sharepoint-list-that-only-relevant-to-the-specific-team/304084#304084)
2. [Restrict user access](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/304393/restrict-user-access/304413#304413)
3. [Manage large lists and libraries](https://support.microsoft.com/office/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)
4. [SharePoint limits - Items in lists and libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits#items-in-lists-and-libraries?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)